# how to store data that is retrieved from db in single process in django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am retrieving data from db. I checked if the response is empty or not.
If empty, I want to add new data from the another table. How can I achieve this in django rest framework.

I want to store list of categories that is checked/unchecked by user. These categories are already stored in category table. The new table for storing with user's selection is user_category table with fields (user[ono-to-one],category[foreignKey],is_selected).
So, while retrieving the list of categories with user's choice, if there's no data then I want to populate the categories along with is_select value where categories are retrieved from categories table.

view.py

```
def goal_achievement_options(request,user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        achievementoptions = AchievementOption.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        if achievementoptions.count() == 0:
            categories = Category.objects.filter(is_service=1)
            serializer = AchieveGoalOptionSerializer(data = categories, context={'request': categories}, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
        serializer = AchieveGoalOptionSerializer(achievementoptions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Can you give more explanations on your problem? How do retrieve data? Where you want to add new data?

Comment: @Headmaster I have updated by question.

Comment: So, get all user categories from the table using django orm and change value in `user_category`. Can you specify, what exactly you can't do?

Comment: I have updated by views.py. Please look on them

Comment: Is it *necessary* to use DRF in this case? Because you use only serializer, and your problem can be solved by simple django

Comment: I am using DRF. for rest api. And I need this so.